# AngularJS transcluded nested directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i'm trying to create an angular directive like this :

```
<radio-button-group group="myGroup" label="My Group" data-model="myModel.attribute">
  <radio-button  id="value_1"  value="1">Value 1</radio-button>
  <radio-button  id="value_2"  value="2">Value 2</radio-button>
</radio-button-group>
```

The main goals are reuse and avoid repeating ng-model on every `<input type="radio" ng-model="myModel.attribute">` and code duplication in general.

I've written the followings:

---

**formjs.js**

```
var formjsModule = angular.module('hp.formjs', []);

// Directive
formjsModule.directive('radioButtonGroup', function () {


  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      dataModel: '@',
      group: '@',
      label: '@?'

    },
    templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
      return 'formjs/radio/radio-group-tpl.html';
    }

  }
}).directive('radioButton', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['^radioButtonGroup'],
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      value: '@',
      dataModel:'@',
      group: '@'
    },

    templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
      return 'formjs/radio/radio-item-tpl.html';
    }

  }


});
```

---

**formjs/radio/radio-item-tpl.html**

```
<input type="radio" name="{{group}}" id="{{group+'_'+id}}" ng-value="value" ng-model="dataModel"/>
```

---

**formjs/radio/radio-group-tpl.html**
    
      {{label}} m: {{dataModel}}

```
  <div class="col-sm-10" id="g_{{group}}" ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm aware of transcluded scope, but i don't see the elegant way to do this binding.

Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

It has to be directive? Wouldn't this be sufficient?

```
// HTML template
<div ng-repeat="option in options">
 <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-value="option"> {{ option }}
</div>
...

// Controller
$scope.selected = null;
$scope.options = ['Radio one', 'Radio two', 'Radio three'];
```

[image]

---

Of course, if you insist, you CAN make it a directive.

Usage in HTML, where `options` is array like above.

```
<radio-group group-name="My group"
             ng-model="selected" 
             options="options"></radio-group>
```

Actual directive

```
app.directive('radioGroup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      groupName: '@',
      options: '=',
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<legend>{{ groupName }}</legend>' + 
              '<div ng-repeat="option in options">' + 
              '  <input type="radio" ' + 
              '         ng-model="$parent.ngModel" ng-value="option"> {{ option }}' + 
              '</div>'
  };
});
```

[image: imgur]

Comment: Sorry! It's my first question. Anyway i need two directives because in the **radio-button** i would use transcluded markup and insert this complex option can be a trap.